# Is possible to parse "off-side" (indentation-based) languages with fparsec?

Tags: parsing, f#, indentation, fparsec

I wish to use FParsec for a python-like language, indentation-based.

I understand that this must be done in the lexing phase, but FParsec don't have a lexing phase. Is possible to use FParsec, or, how can feed it after lexing?

P.D: I'm new at F#, but experienced in other languages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Here is a [relevant article](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/wiki/Parsing-indentation-based-syntax-with-FParsec) by FParsec author. If you want to go deeper on the subject, [this paper](http://michaeldadams.org/papers/layout_parsing/LayoutParsing.pdf) might worth a read. The paper points out that there are multiple packages for indentation-aware parsing that based on Parsec, the parser combinator that inspires FParsec.

FParsec doesn't have a separate lexing phase but instead it fuses lexing and parsing to a single phase. IMO indentation-aware parsing is better to be done with parser combinators (FParsec) than parser generators (fslex/fsyacc). The reason is that you need to manually track current indentation and report good error messages based on contexts.

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not allowing me to edit the question but if anyone finds out that the "relevant article" is dead and is interested to read it, it's in github: https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/wiki/Parsing-indentation-based-syntax-with-FParsec